# textbox not showing autocomplete, the textbox just blinks

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

Every single comment i have been reading said that this code works.. 
But when I try to type in text to the textbox no autocomplete appears and it just blinks.. please help,, i m new to winforms

```
Private Sub txsCusID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txsCusID.TextChanged
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT fname + ' ' + lname AS clist FROM tblclient WHERE id LIKE '%" + txsCusID.Text.ToString + "%'", sqlconstr)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "list")
    Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("clist").ToString())
    Next
    txsCusID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    txsCusID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
    txsCusID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
End Sub
```

Comment: What is sqlconstr? If its an actual string, I don't think it will work as SqlCommand expects an actual SqlConnection object. If you try and step through the code, what happens?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 the sqlconstr is a sqlclient.sqlconnection. i tried putting MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("clist").ToString()) after the col.add... and it displayed the 'name' so i know the query is not returning null.

Comment: try removing the .ToString() to make it `col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("clist"))`  ToString will give you the Object.ToString which is usually just the "name" as you said

Comment: [Switch to C# dot com](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/10-reasons-why-visual-basic-is-better-than-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Here give this a try... I would suggest setting your table up and then loop through while adding to your source...

```
    Dim dtCustomerNames As DataTable
    dtCustomerNames = ds.Tables(0)


    For Each row As DataRow In dtCustomerNames.Rows
        'You have to continue to add your data here...'
        txsCusID.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add((row.Item("clist").ToString))
    Next

    txsCusID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    txsCusID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
```

Let me know how it works out for you...

Thanks!